# VBA add more columns to ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add more columns to Listbox
Have to change somwthing in RowSource?

If is something with to put array, but im not doing it

```
Sub preencherListBox()
Dim ultimaLinha As Long
Dim linha As Integer
'retorna ao valor ultima linha preenchida
ultimaLinha = Folha1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
'percorre da segunda linha até a última linha e atribui o valor da primeira e segunda coluna
For linha = 2 To ultimaLinha
   Visualizar.ListBox1.AddItem Folha1.Range("A" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Folha1.Range("B" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Folha1.Range("C" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Folha1.Range("D" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Folha1.Range("E" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Folha1.Range("F" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Folha1.Range("G" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = Folha1.Range("H" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = Folha1.Range("I" & linha)
   Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 9) = Folha1.Range("J" & linha)
   'Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 10) = Folha1.Range("K" & linha)
   'Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 11) = Folha1.Range("L" & linha)
   'Visualizar.ListBox1.List(Visualizar.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 12) = Folha1.Range("M" & linha)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, change that `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: You can't use AddItem if the listbox has more than 9 columns, put the data for the listbox into an array and use List instead.

Comment: And how i do it ?

Comment: @HugTheCode Did you find an answer to your question? You got two of them, feel free to mark the preferred one as accepted by ticking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use AddItem if the listbox has more than 9 columns, put the data for the listbox into an array and use List instead.

```
Option Explicit

Sub preencherListBox()
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim ultimaLinha As Long
Dim linha As Integer

    'retorna ao valor ultima linha preenchida
    ultimaLinha = folha1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

    arrData = folha1.Range("A2:M" & ultimaLinha).Value
    
    With Visualizar.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 13
        .List = arrData
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Fyi Posted some additions to your answer which shows the right direction if used without binding to a RowSource +:) @norie

Answer (score 0):

**A)** Generally

- a (listbox) control **bound to data** doesn't accept the [`AddItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/additem-method) method, i.e. `AddItem` fails raising a run-time error 70.

So it will be necessary to decide between

- a) changing the `RowSource` property either manually or via code assignment or
- b) assignments to the array list property either via array or `AddItem`.

**B)** If used without bound RowSource, @Norie 's statement (though leading to the right direction) needs some additions

> "You can't use `AddItem` if the listbox has more than 9 columns."

- It's true that by default the use of `AddItem` provides only for **10 columns** (with zero-based list column indexes ranging from 0 to 9).
- Note that `.AddItem` looping through each cell in a given range is time consuming compared to assigning an entire datafield array to the listbox'es `.List` property.
- Initializing the listbox via an empty list assignment plus eventual row deletion
  would actually enable a later `AddItem` execution to fill more than 10 columns:

**Proof**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        ReDim tmp(0 To 0, 0 To 11)
        .List = tmp
        .ColumnCount = 12
        .ColumnWidths = "30;30;;;;;;;;40;41;42"
    .RemoveItem 0
        
        .AddItem "one"
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "two"
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 10) = "eleven"
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 11) = "twelve"
    End With
End Sub
```